# Auto sum without need to reenter the resolved numbers list of numbers/int separated by white space

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, spaces

I would like to know how to take a longish list of numbers/int separated by white spaces and work out the total/sum all in a few lines of code.

I have tried adapting ( I am a beginner doing tutorials) some code on this site for the manual entry of integers that then sums up but I would like to see by some simple loop use that I can paste or copy the numbers in at top end and then have a sum calc at end without the need to enter the numbers into some box. I get the following code that I copied and adpated simply by changing raw_input to input for Python 3 but that produced the box. I have tried to manually define numbers at top but get a mess of errors.

```
>>>mylist = input("Enter a list of numbers, SEPERATED by WHITE SPACE(3 5 66 etc.): ")
# now you can use the split method of strings to get a list
>>>mylist = mylist.split() # splits on white space by default
# to split on commas -> mylist.split(",")

# mylist will now look something like. A list of strings.
['1', '44', '56', '2'] # depending on input of course

# so now you can do
>>>total = sum(int(i) for i in mylist)
# converting each string to an int individually while summing as you go
```

The last line above says "summing as you go" but I want to put in the data once at the beginning and not manually feed in again to some box and then have a sum at end. I want to go straight to sum total without this need to enter into a box.
I started trying to enter the list of numbers separated by white space as a string but got nowhere and made mistakes with the map function

Comment: The above answer does not sum it just produces the input box where numbers are entered with white spaces and then if Return key is entered it prints those numbers with no total?

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner doha and I added print(total and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to assign the list to a variable.

You do that by `mylist = [1, 44, 56, 2]` where `mylist` is the variable to which the `list` of integers `[1, 44, 56, 2]` is assigned to.

```
In [9]: mylist = [1, 44, 56, 2]                                                                                                                                                                         

In [10]: total = sum(i for i in mylist)                                                                                                                                                                 

In [11]: total                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[11]: 103
```

Comment: You guys get the beginners who are really beginners to use their brains and thanks for all the comments that I have now finally worked through. You certainly dont spoon feed anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "reduce" function which applies a specified function to all elements in a list. Also, It is faster.

```
    from functools import reduce
    import operator

    yourStr = "1 44 56 2"
    print( reduce(operator.add,[int(i) for i in yourStr.split()]) )
```